# Losing formatting upon fetching text from API (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, api, templates, literals

I'm still very new to this coding world and so please bear with me :)

**Problem:**

I'm grabbing text from an API.
This API contains text with spaces, new lines and such in free text (from google spreadsheet that turned into API)

When I'm reading this everything is compressed into one long string. Is there way to keep the spaces and such?

**The unwanted output:**
You can see the output on this link: http://azmi.digital/apitexttest/

**Correct output**
If you open up the console, you can see the new lines, spaces etc.

**Why is the formating not following on the output on the webpage?**

Thanks in advance for replying <3

Comment: When setting HTML content, white-space laterals are not treated like line-breaks (`<br>`) and  non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`). You will need to convert these `\n` characters to `<br>` elements, or set the `white-space` to `pre`. Why don't you post some sample text you get back from the API fetch?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mr.Polywhirl !

I can't post the fetch full fetch since Stackoverflow is limiting my text but I put it on the page I linked before:   http://azmi.digital/apitexttest/

The fetch data response being shown in console.

Answer (score 0):

Okey so following @Mr.Polywhirl s suggestion of replacing the \n with  I ended up with this:
**cell** being my old text and **snippet** being my new text.

**THIS did not work, I'm not sure why.**
let snippet = cell.replaceAll('\n','
');

**Found this solution on google and it worked!**
let snippet = cell.replace(/\n/g, "
");

If an explanation could be made I'd be happy, otherwise the issue is solved!